# Is there a response to Stagflation that isn't austerity?

Tags: inflation, economic-growth

A reason why Keynesian economics got discredited and replaced by the now dominant Washington Consensus, was because of the 1970's stagflaysh according to David Harvey: https://newlearningonline.com/new-learning/chapter-4/david-harvey-a-brief-history-of-neoliberalism

Is there a Keynesian response to Stagflation that does not involve austerity?